# About implementation of getResource in GenericApplicationContext

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Spring-web,webmvc 4.1.6
Thymeleaf 2.1

I have been working for manualy configuration of Thymeleaf in SpringBoot.
I want to set path in ServletContextTemplateResolver with "classpath:" prefix.
What can I do to deal with this problem?

```
@Bean
public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");        
    templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
    return templateResolver;
 }
```

But it doesn't work. The reason is the code below.
In the org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext

```
@Override
public Resource getResource(String location) {
    if (this.resourceLoader != null) {
        return this.resourceLoader.getResource(location);    // with setting of template resolver
    }
    return super.getResource(location);    // without setting of template resolver
}
```

Without any settings of ServletContextTemplateResolver,
GenericApplicationContext.getResource is called.

With setting of it 
StandardRoot.getResourceAsStream is called.
But this method doesn't have implementation of support "class: " prefix.

---

**Successfully to getResource**

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/GenericApplicationContext.html#getResource-java.lang.String-

"ClassPathResource is implemented"

```
@Override
public Resource getResource(String location) {
    Assert.notNull(location, "Location must not be null");
    if (location.startsWith("/")) {
        return getResourceByPath(location);
    }
    else if (location.startsWith(CLASSPATH_URL_PREFIX)) {
        return new ClassPathResource(location.substring(CLASSPATH_URL_PREFIX.length()), getClassLoader());
    }
    else {
        try {
            // Try to parse the location as a URL...
            URL url = new URL(location);
            return new UrlResource(url);
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            // No URL -> resolve as resource path.
            return getResourceByPath(location);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Failed getResource**

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/webresources/StandardRoot.html#getResource(java.lang.String)

In this code, the prefix is not implemented so , I realized that I can't use "class:" prefix for the property of ServletContextTemplateResolver.

In org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot

```
@Override
public InputStream getResourceAsStream(String path) {

    if (path == null)
        return (null);

    if (!path.startsWith("/") && GET_RESOURCE_REQUIRE_SLASH)
        return null;

    WebResourceRoot resources = context.getResources();
    if (resources != null) {
         return resources.getResource(path).getInputStream();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to load your templates as classpath items with *optional* support for a *prefix* path, you should use the `ClassLoaderResourceResolver` instead of the `ServletContextTemplateResolver` (the latter resolves tempaltes relatively to your web application context, i.e. under the */WEB-INF/* directory):

```
@Bean
public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    ITemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setPrefix("templates/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");        
    templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
    return templateResolver;
 }
```

Note that there is no need to append the ***classpath:*** prefix to your templates path prefix, as the classloader resolver looks by default into your classpath.

You may need to take a look at each of the `org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.TemplateResolver` subclasses which affords different techniques for loading resources:

- [`org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ClassLoaderTemplateResolver`](http://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/2.0.2/org/thymeleaf/templateresolver/ClassLoaderTemplateResolver.html)
- [`org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver`](http://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/2.0.2/org/thymeleaf/resourceresolver/ServletContextTemplateResolver.html)
- [`org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.UrlTempalteResolver`](http://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/2.0.2/org/thymeleaf/templateresolver/UrlTemplateResolver.html)
- [`org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.FileTemplateResolver`](http://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/2.0.2/org/thymeleaf/templateresolver/FileTemplateResolver.html)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry I was able to solve this problem.

http://forum.thymeleaf.org/Loading-templates-from-external-source-td4025309.html

I used ClassLoaderTemplateResolver instead.

`classLoaderTemplateResolver.setPrefix("templates/");`